# Function within a function

Tags: python, function

This is what I have:

```
def function1(pixel, color):
  setColor(pixel,color)


def function2(pixel):
  x = min(getRed(pixel), getGreen(pixel), getBlue(pixel))
  ???
  function1(pixel,color)
```

The 1st function I am just changing an individual pixel in a picture to a built in color.

In the 2nd function I am trying to set an individual pixel to a shade of grey, by getting the lowest of the pixels origin values and setting them all the same. Easy enough by itself, but I can't figure out what to stick in between my first and last lines of function2 while still using function1 in it. Everything I try gives me an error in function1. I know I could just make it `setColor(pix,makeColor(x,x,x)` but function1 is restricting me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `setColor(pix, makeColor(x, x, x))` works, why not just pass those arguments that work to `function1()` then?

```
function1(pixel, makeColor(x, x, x))
```

The result of `makeColor(x, x, x)` is an object too, and will be passed to `function1` as the `color` argument.